# use value from ng-repeat to set value in component

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to pass a value from my ng-repeat into a component but I can't figure how to pass the value in the ng-click.

```
    <span md-prevent-menu-close md-toggle height="100px">Selecteer status</span>
    <ul class="md-toggle">
        <li md-prevent-menu-close ng-repeat="x in vm.telephonyInfo.phone.phoneRichPresenceStateOptions" ng-click="vm.currentPhoneRichPresenceState = {{x.text}}; vm.setPhoneRichPresenceState();" >{{x.text}}</li>
    </ul>
```

If I use:

```
ng-click="vm.currentPhoneRichPresenceState = 'asd';
```

Then it works, but:

```
ng-click="vm.currentPhoneRichPresenceState = '{{x.text}}';
```

Is rendered as a string.

Comment: have you tried `vm.currentPhoneRichPresenceState = x.text` ?

Comment: Ah. Of course, the double brackets are needed to render the text in the dom. Thanks, such a silly mistake.

Comment: most `ng-` attributes don't need `{{ }}`